# SQLite query isn't working

Tags: android, sqlite

Cant anyone tell me why I the flowing query isn't working properly?
It suppose to return true if there are types with same name and different _ID(Key)

```
//****************************************************************************************************//
//  ifExistButMy(String typeName,int ID) FUNCTION: return true if type name exists but mine(ID)
// 
//****************************************************************************************************//    

public boolean ifExistButMy(String typeName,int ID){
    Cursor cur;
    SQLiteDatabase db = content.getWritableDatabase();
    cur = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null,TYPE_NAME + "='" + typeName + "'"+" AND "+ _ID+ " <> " + ID,null, null, null, null);
    return cur.moveToFirst(); //returns false if cur is empty   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] mFields=new String[]{"columnName1","columnName2",....}

cur = db.query(TABLE_NAME, mFields,TYPE_NAME + "='" + typeName + "'"+" AND "+ _ID+ " <> " + ID,null, null, null, null);
```

your second argument is null rather than having which field to be selected

Comment: Yes, but null gives me all columns. You sure thats might be the reason?

Comment: this may be the reason, but not 100% sure

Comment: Unfortunately it's not helping.